# how to output in 5-minute interval?(mysql )

Tags: mysql

I want to output a time interval.
Stores at one minute intervals.
query is:

```
select datetime + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
from ch1
where datetime between '2016-07-12 17:26:00' and '2016-07-13 09:17:00'
```

but output is

```
2016-07-12 17:31:00  
2016-07-12 17:32:00  
2016-07-12 17:33:00  
2016-07-12 17:34:00  
2016-07-12 17:35:00  
2016-07-12 17:36:00 ...
```

I want to output.

```
2016-07-12 17:26:00  
2016-07-12 17:31:00  
2016-07-12 17:36:00  
2016-07-12 17:41:00  
2016-07-12 17:46:00  
2016-07-12 17:51:00 ...
```

Comment: Want you to get output independent from your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `ch1` table already has the timestamp data you want.  If this be the case, then you can simply choose records from every 5 minutes by using the `MINUTE()` function along with a modulus:

```
SELECT datetime + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
FROM ch1
WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2016-07-12 17:26:00' AND '2016-07-13 09:17:00' AND
      MINUTE(datetime) % 5 = 0
```

Actually, if you want `2006-07-12 17:26:00` to be the first record in the result set, then you can offset the modulus calculation:

```
SELECT datetime + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
FROM ch1
WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2016-07-12 17:26:00' AND '2016-07-13 09:17:00' AND
      (MINUTE(datetime) - 1) % 5 = 0
```

Comment: I solved like "SELECT 
FROM_UNIXTIME(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/300 AS SIGNED)*300)
 FROM ch1
where datetime between '2016-07-12 17:26:00' and '2016-07-13 09:17:00' GROUP BY 1"

Comment: @C.Seon, then you should add this as answer, and mark your own as correct, because this answer solves completely another problem.

Comment: @vp_arth Wouldn't it be more accurate to say that my answer completely solves the question, but that the real problem was not exactly the original question?

Comment: May be. Question just can be interpreted both way. I upvote your answer anyway.